# Unity/C# error when setting gravity for a planet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When i try to attach my GravityBody script and my GravityAttractor script these 3 errors pop up :

> Assets/Scripts/GravityAttractor.cs(15,42): error CS1502: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.Quaternion.FromToRotation(UnityEngine.Vector3,
>   UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Assets/Scripts/GravityAttractor.cs(15,65): error CS1503: Argument `#2'
>   cannot convert`float' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'
>
> Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs(21,29): error CS1061: Type
>   `UnityEngine.Rigidbody' does not contain a definition for`
>   MoveDirection' and no extension method `MoveDirection' of type`
>   UnityEngine.Rigidbody' could be found. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference?

This is the code for the scripts ;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GravityBody : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public GravityAttractor attractor;
    private Transform myTransform;

    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        myTransform = transform;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        if (attractor){

            attractor.Attract(myTransform);
        }

    }
}

    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GravityAttractor : MonoBehaviour {

    public float gravity = -10;

    public void Attract(Transform myTransform) {
        Vector3 gravityUp = (myTransform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 localUp = myTransform.up;

        myTransform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(localUp,gravity) * myTransform.rotation;
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,targetRotation,(50f * Time.deltaTime));
    }


}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Do you not understand what the error messages mean?

Comment: I can t fix it  and i didn't find the solution on the internet and my code won't run because of these errors . Can you help me with a solution for fixing these errors ?

Answer (score 1):

> Assets/Scripts/GravityAttractor.cs(15,42): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Quaternion.FromToRotation(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments

This one is pretty straight-forward - just read the error message. "Quaternion.FromToRotation(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments" means your code has some incorrect arguments for that method (specifically, Quaternion.FromToRotation(*your arguments*). You can see the expected arguments [here, at the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) (look near the top). You can see that the method takes two Vector3 objects. I'm guessing you may have just accidentally wrote `gravity` instead of `gravityUp`?

> Assets/Scripts/GravityAttractor.cs(15,65): error CS1503: Argument #2'
>     cannot convertfloat' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Same problem. The compiler is telling you that it tried to call the `Quaternion.FromToRotation` method, but it couldn't change the `gravity` float into a Vector3 (cuz that's what it needed)

> Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs(21,29): error CS1061: Type  UnityEngine.Rigidbody' does not contain a definition for
>     MoveDirection' and no extension method MoveDirection' of type
>     UnityEngine.Rigidbody' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Well, you didn't show this code, but that error means that somewhere in your code, you have `.MoveDirection` on a `RigidBody` variable somewhere. Again, the error message says " UnityEngine.Rigidbody' does not contain a definition for
  MoveDirection'" - and that's exactly what it means. You called `.MoveDirection` on the wrong variable